# Zip code map search using Web.py framework

Tags: zip, area, web.py

I am learning as I build a random web application using python and web.py framework.

In this simple app I am going to have users search specific results in a 5 mile zip code radius. They enter their zip code and hit search and should get the results.

Now I have no clue on how to implement this or even where to start. I googled but nothing seems to help a beginner like me.

Please kindly advise,
Thank you!

Comment: What tools do you bring to the table: Can you code in Python? Any prior programming language experience? Do you know - and to which extend - html, css, javascript and the http protocol? Any such detail may help us help you, because you only list the task, and to my understanding, that you do not know where to start. That is ok, but answers are more probable, when we know better where you could already make progress, and where you may need to go back learning the basics. So please be more specific. Or did you arlready code a similar web or commandline app? Thanks.

Comment: Hello thank you Dilettant,I can code in python basics and do have prior programming language experience (java, php) but certainly not an expert. I do know html (basics) but not css and javascript. HTTP protocol (basics) but any link on that would be great that you think I should read. Right now i am making my app in web.py and am making slow but steady progress. I am learning as I go so that is also helping me understand things as they come along. I am coding in pycharm on a mac machine. Thanks